# UpdatePanel Not Refreshing ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I need some items added to `ListBox` whenever a new `TreeNode` is selected.

I would like this to happen without the entire page posting back.

To this end I have the following markup, where `ListBox` has been placed inside an `UpdatePanel` with (I think) the required `Trigger`s:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:TreeView ID="testTreeView" runat="server" Height="304px" OnSelectedNodeChanged="testTreeView_SelectedNodeChanged" Width="257px">
            <LeafNodeStyle ForeColor="Yellow" />
        </asp:TreeView>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
            </ContentTemplate>

            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="testTreeView" EventName="SelectedNodeChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </td>
</tr>
```

#### testTreeView_SelectedNodeChanged

```
protected void testTreeView_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListBox1.Items.Clear();

    var selectedNode = testTreeView.SelectedNode;

    var userList = AddUsersToList(selectedNode);

    foreach (var item in userList)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item["Title"].ToString());
    }
}
```

When I try using the above without any update panels at all, the code works just find, but the whole page posts back when a new `TreeNode` is selected.

After adding the update panel, I can see that the event still fires, but no items are added to `ListBox1`, making me think that the `UpdatePanel` is not refreshing when selecting a new `TreeNode`.

---

I also tried putting both controls in the same `UpdatePanel`, but with the same results (event fires but `ListBox` is not updated):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="testTreeView" EventName="SelectedNodeChanged" />
    </Triggers>

    <ContentTemplate>
        <table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:TreeView ID="testTreeView" runat="server" Height="304px" OnSelectedNodeChanged="testTreeView_SelectedNodeChanged" Width="257px">
                        <LeafNodeStyle ForeColor="Yellow" />
                    </asp:TreeView>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Height="276px" Width="305px"></asp:ListBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Put your `Treeview` inside the update panel also.

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava I tried that but with the same results. I added the code above.

Comment: Try to set `UpdatePanel2.Update();` after binding items in ListBox and outside the `foreach` loop.Let me know if it is working.

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava Still the same result ..

Comment: Remove `UpdateMode="conditional"` and `<Triggers>` from `UpdatePanel`.Let me know if this work.

Comment: Doing that with the call to `Update()` results in an error (must be set to "conditional" to call `Update()`). Aftter removing the `UpdateMode` attribute, I am getting the same results as I did originally

Comment: I have tried in my solution and it is working.I wonder why it is not working on your project.

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava Does your panel sit around a table like mine does? Do you think you could post the code you used then I can try recreating it exactly

Comment: One possible difference between your code and mine may be in binding of `TreeView` Control.How you are binding your `TreeView` control i mean how data populated in `TreeView`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124634/discussion-between-saurabh-srivastava-and-bassie).

Answer (score 0):

Call `UpdatePanel2.Update()` after `ListBox1.Items.Add()` or use `UpdateMode="Always"` instead of `"conditional"` in markup.

Comment: I tried this in conjunction with my second attempt in the Question (both controls in 1 panel), but it still doesn't work